# Как объединить данные нескольких столбцов в один?

Tags: google-spreadsheet

Как объединить данные с нескольких столбцов в один?

Пример того, что должно получиться:

[image: Как объединить данные нескольких столбцов в один в Spreadsheets?]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Используйте формулу с фигурными скобками, перечисляя диапазоны через ";".

В вашем случае формула будет такая:

```
={A1:A5;B1:B4;C1:C3}
```

Comment: Спасибо. Ларчик просто открывался. А тут поможешь: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/829756/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5-%D0%B2-%D1%8F%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%B9%D0%BA%D0%B5-google-spreadsheet

Answer (score 0):

Решено.

```
={query(A1:A;"select * where (A) > 0");query(B1:B;"select * where (B) > 0");query(C1:C;"select * where (C) > 0")}
```