# Как перезаписать данные в ячейке Google spreadsheet с помощью скрипта?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-spreadsheet

Имеются данные в ячейках B7 и B8 (наглядно на рисунке).
[image: Старые данные в ячейках B1 & B2]

Какой скрипт поможет записать эти данные в ячейки B1 и B2? (результат на рисунке)
[image: Результат работы скрипта]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Используйте [copyTo](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#copyTo(Range))

В вашем случае - это:

```
SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange("B7:B8").copyTo(SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange("B1:B2"))
```